# R, individual ?argument function that leads to own online help

Tags: function, r, key, definition

I have an internal wiki and I created a function w(argument), which directly opens the corresponding page on my wiki using browseURL(url, browser). However, instead of w(argument), I'd like to replace it by #argument, similar to ?argument. Does somebody know if such a function definition with a shortkey is possible within R

Thanks a lot for your help

BR
Martin

Answer (score 4):

No. What you are looking for is to define a new *unary* operator in R, and that isn't possible. (And `#` is the comment character in R so is used already anyway, so that wouldn't work.)

This [post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-March/048683.html) by Brian Ripley, in response to a similarly motivated question, has a bit more explanation (not much)

Answer (score 1):

'#' starts a comment in R, so that will never get passed the parser. You'll have to modify the core and recompile R if you really want #foo to do something other than nothing.

Comment: Any other shortkey is fine as well, # was just an example, sorry was not clear enough

Comment: What do you mean by a 'shortkey'? There's no such concept in R's syntax. The ?foo notation is a special piece of syntax that is mapped to help("foo") at a low level. Remember R is a functional language, not a macro language. Your users should embrace w(foo) notation.

Comment: "shortkey" == "unary operator" operator in R parlance, but essentially you are right; as Brian Ripley states, you can't add unary operators to R without altering the parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can change what ?foo does by reassigning it:

```
> assign("?",function(x){cat("HALP!\n")})
> ?foo
HALP!
```

Obviously you'd make it fall through to the default help system if the arg isn't what you are interested in, but this is pretty ugly.

Comment: See the `FindFn2.R` file in the sos source package for an example.  In that case it uses `???` .

Answer (score 0):

You could define a binary operator, then pass anything in to the first argument, e.g.,

```
"%w%" <- function(x, y) w(y)
1%w%argument
```

It's 4 keys rather than 1, but that's about as close as you can get without major reworking of R.